# Unable to get custom span in PCF metrics using spring cloud sleuth

Tags: spring, metrics, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have created a spring boot application with spring cloud sleuth. For POC purposes, I used zipkin on 
my local machine and I am able to instrument a external service which is not instrumented by creating 
manual span. I reffered below link.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/1.2.x/multi/multi__customizations.html

Now, When I move to PCF environment, then I am unable to collect proper custom spans.
PCF metrics always shows parent span and service with total time taken.
Could anyone please let me know where I am going wrong.

Zipkin Output:-

[image]

PCF Metrics:-

[image]

**UPDATE**
screen shot for Zipkin with @NewSpan.

[image]

PCF metrics screen shot without call hierachy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a different logging pattern to make it work with PCF Metrics AFAIR. You need the parent span to be present in logs. Set the property `logging.pattern.level: "%clr(%5p) %clr([${spring.application.name:-},%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}]){yellow}"`. Check this example: https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pcf-metrics-trace-example-spring

Comment: I have mentioned same pattern in application.yml file. The issue is - If I use zipkin then @NewSpan is working and it is showing call hierarchy, but when I deploy same app to PCF(by removing zipkin dependency) then in PCF metrics it is not showing call hierarchy.
I have attached updated screens shot.

Answer (score 0):

PCF metrics does  not support custom spans, it only shows the respomse time distribution span that corresponds to http request routed by goRouter.

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh, could you please point me to some documentation mentioning this?